# How do i create a fuction that tells me what is the last card available in my deck?

Tags: c

Hello everyone I am new to programming and I need your help.

I am developing a game called Hanabi in C language.
My question is how do I create a function or how do I make my `last_deckccard` variable tell me the last card in the `deck_n` deck and give me the value always updated, because once that card is used it has to move to the next and can never repeat.

Basically I want you to deal 5 cards to each player and the `last_deckcard` variable is always the last card available in the deck.
Sorry if I did not explain well but if anyone has a suggestion of how to say thank you, now if my code is disorganized and confused sorry is my first game.

The subroutine I have questions on is `get_card`:

```
get_card(int v[], int p1){
    last_deckcard = 49-p1;
    v[p1] = deck_n[last_deckcard];
}
```

My output is:

> 5 4 4 3 3 *********5 4 4 3 3

But should be:

> 5 4 4 3 3 *********2 2 1 1 1

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h> //Jogo HANABI
#include <math.h>
#include "graphsettings.h"
#include <time.h>
void show_deck();
shuffle(int v[], int dim);
inter(int deck_n[]);
color(int deck_n[], int index);


int deck[50];
//deck com os numeros todos do baralho
int deck_n[50] = {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5};
//deck para determinar a cor da carta;verde/azul/amarelo/vermelho/ branco
int deck_c[50] ={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5};
//variaveis para a mao dos jogadores , 
int hand_player1[5], hand_player2[5], table[5]= {0,0,0,0,0}, discard_table[5][5];

int last_deckcard;

int main(void) 
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int k;
    system("mode con:cols=180 lines=50" ); //define o tamanho da console
    //give 5 cards to each player
    for (k=0; k < 5; k++){
        get_card(hand_player1, k);
        get_card(hand_player2, k);
    }
return 0;
}
//A subrotine that show's the deck 
void show_deck()
{
    int i;
    for (i= 0; i<50; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", deck_n[i]);
    }
}
//swap positions between a and b in vector v[]
swap (int v[], int a, int b) 
{ 
    int aux = v[a]; 
    v[a] = v[b]; 
    v[b] = aux; 
}
// subroutine that shuffles a vector by creating a second vector array
// random r [] and sorting the latter, replicating all exchanges
// in the vector v []
shuffle(int v[], int dim){
    int r[dim],k,m;

    for (k=1;k<dim; k++)
    {
       r[k] = rand();//creation of random vector with same dimension as deck_n vector
    }
  for (m= 1; m<=dim-1 ;m++){
    for (k=1; k<=dim-m; k++)
    {
        if (r[k] > r[k+1]){
        swap(r, k, k+1);
        swap(v, k, k+1);//replicate swap to deck_n vector to shuffle
      }
  }
 }
}
//function to determine the last card available in the deck
//lastcard(int v[], int dim)
//{
//  int last_deckcard, i;
//  
//  for(i=0;i<dim; i++)
//  {
//      last_deckcard = deck_n[dim-i];
//  }
//}
// subroutine that fetches the last available card from the deck
// and put in the vector v [] at position p1
get_card(int v[], int p1){
    last_deckcard = 49-p1;
    v[p1] = deck_n[last_deckcard];
}
//interface
inter(int deck_n[])
{   
    int a=0,i;

    for (i= 0; i<10; i++, a+=5){
//    setColor(2,2);
//    showRectAt(0+a,0,5,6);
//    setColor(2,2);
//    showRectAt(1+a,1,3,4); ter uma carta prenchida totalmente
//    setColor(2,2);
//    showRectAt(2+a,2,1,2);
//    resetColor();
      printf("\n");
      showRectAt(0+a,0,5,6);
      gotoxy(2+a,3);
      setColor(15,0);
      printf("%d",deck_n[i]);
      resetColor();
      printf("\n\n\n\n");
   }
}
// subroutine that through the position of the number in the deck vector cannot
// determine the color of the card to which this number belongs
// for example: deck_n [3] = 1 which is equal to deck_c [3] = 1 logo is green
color(int deck_n[], int index)
{
    deck_n[index] = deck_c[index];

        switch(deck_c[index])
        {
            case 1://cor de verde
                setColor(10,0);
                break;
            case 2://cor de azul
                setColor(11,0);
                //printf("o numero %d tem cor azul ",deck_n[index]);
                break;  
            case 3://cor de amarelo
                setColor(6,0);
                break;
            case 4://cor de vermelho
                setColor(12,0);
                break;
            case 5://cor de branco
                setColor(15,0);
                break;      
        }
}
```

Comment: Why 49 in `last_deckcard = 49-p1;`? There are 2 players.  Maybe keep track of deck count with a separate variable?

Comment: Yes i already tried that by creating a fuction above but it didnt work